# Bar length in Excel chart - Stack and scale width

Tags: excel, charts, scale

I've created a bar chart in Excel and then used the "Picture or texture fill" option, with the "Stack and Scale with" option set to 1.

[image: settings]

[image: output]

However, if I attempt to change the bottom row to 19 instead of 18, it completely screws up the scaling of the images and I have no idea why or no idea where the setting to change this is? The largest value is 22.2 so I don't see how the 19 can be too big to render the individual men. Any ideas why this might be happening or how to amend this?

[image]

I've hosted my Excel file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/menscalingissue) (am I allowed to do this?!) to show what I mean.

Thanks,

Comment: Please make visible the horizontal axis. Then you will see where the problem is. It will not start with minimum 0 anymore. Set the minimum to 0 again. Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you! Knew it would be something so simple! Do you want to reply as an answer and I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Problem solved was ironic. An answer would be how one could influence the auto behavior of the chart axes. It is not meaningful in so many cases.